# WebClient Spring boot no puedo llamar a una api externa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Tengo un problema que no logro solventar.

Estoy migrando desde restemplate a webclient en springboot pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Si llamo a la api de un tercero (la que deseo llamar desde spring boot con el webclient) me arroja error.  Creo que tengo mal como estoy enviando el body en webclient.

La api a la que llamo como requisito me pide enviar un texto entre comilla como json. Enviando desde postman funciona perfecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero llamando desde

```
WebClient client = 
    WebClient.builder()
  .baseUrl("https://apitercero.com")

  .build();
  
  Mono<?> responseMono = client.post()
    .uri("/portal/xxxxx/yyyy.svc/json/EncryptQS?user_name=user&password=passs")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .bodyValue(body)   // Error de llamada a api externa 
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class);
    
    responseMono.subscribe(responseBody -> {
       
        System.out.println("Response Body: " + responseBody);
    });
```

Si no pongo el bodyvalue envia se comunica y me devuelve el error de que falta el envió del body por lo cual hasta la api del tercero llego y puedo ver la respuesta.

Pero si agrego el body.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from POST https://apitercero.com/portal/xxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy.svc/json/EncryptQS?user_name=user&password=pass
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:218) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ? 500 from POST https://urlapitercero.com/portal/xxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyy.svc/json/EncryptQS?user_name=user&pass [DefaultWebClient]

Agradeceré cualquier orientación .

Comment: Yo tengo un problema similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76929286/webclient-presenting-error-org-springframework-web-reactive-function-client-web

Comment: Creería que siempre debes enviar el Body... Según la imagen del Postman la estás enviando. No veo tu definición del Body al usar el WebClient. Si es por asuntos de seguridad, usa una configuración para que traiga el secreto de un Vault.

Comment: joseluisbz el body es un string con los datos que nos pide la api

Comment: El error 500, se debe a un error al que le estás haciendo el Request, y por tanto, podría ser que al no enviarle el Body, falle internamente al servicio que consultas.

Comment: Claro pero el body se lo estoy enviando justamente bodyvalue por eso no se.

Comment: Pensaría que el error no está relacionado con tu mensaje sino con lo que te podría salir más abajo, algo como:  `Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
  at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:102)
  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1712)`

Comment: Por otro lado, trata de imprimir el Body que procesa el WebClient (no imprimir la variable del Body directamente), sino a través de la interface `WebClient.Builder`, revisa el método `Builder filter(ExchangeFilterFunction filter)` en esa interface.
Porque así te das cuenta lo que realmente está enviando el WebClient (no solo lo que tu le pones).

Comment: Trata de imprimir tus excepciones suprimidas.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-suppressed-exceptions#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20a%20suppressed%20exception,try%20block%20is%20then%20suppressed.

Comment: Encontre el error y obviamente era totalmente mi culpa, lo pase por alto mil veces. El body va entre comillas como requisito de la api yo lo enviaba como "body.." y va como "\"body....\"" para que salga con las comillas.